# Django ModelForm with initial data not shown on redisplay

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django ModelForm with some initial data passed to it. Which is working fine so far.

But, if the user doesn't fill in all data, or makes another mistake the initial value will not be looked up again on redisplaying the form.

Here's a piece of code:

```
class TrainingAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = TrainingTasks
    fields = ('task','ac_reg','date','wo_no')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TrainingAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['task'].required = False
    self.fields['task'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
    self.fields['date'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()

def clean_task(self):
    return
```

An in forms.py:

```
def add_trainingtask(request, task_id):

if request.POST:
    form = TrainingAddForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        tt = TrainingTasks(
            trainee = request.user,
            task = Tasks.objects.get(pk=task_id),
            date = form.cleaned_data['date'],
            ac_reg = form.cleaned_data['ac_reg'],
            wo_no = form.cleaned_data['wo_no'],
        )
        tt.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/tot/tasks/')

else:
    form = TrainingAddForm(initial = {"task": task_id})

return render_to_response('admin/tot/trainingtasks/add.html', {
        'form': form,
        'task_id': task_id
    },
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
)
```

If a user misses to fill in i.e. the date (which is mandatory) the form will be redisplayed showing an error (field required), but the underlying record of task_id is not shown anymore.
The ID is still there and it's also possible to save the record (after correcting the error), so that's almost an irritating error for the user.

I guess I missed some piece of code, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Question doesn't really make sense. Are you saying that the `task` form field is empty after reloading the page?

Comment: Yes, exactly this happens. The task_id is still there, but the according record will not be shown anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the logic of your form or your view.

You've included the task field, yet disabled the field. With the task field disabled, the value isn't going to be in the request.POST collection.

In your view, you're passing the form the task_id parameter as the initial data, and if the request.method is a POST, you're retrieving the Task object from the database.

It seems like the Task is something that you want to assign to TrainingTask, but not it's not necessarily something you want to include in the form. Given that, I would:

```
#forms.py
class TrainingAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrainingTasks
        fields = ('ac_reg','date','wo_no',)
        #not include the task

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrainingAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()

#views.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from your_app.forms import TrainingAddForm
from your_app.models import Task, TrainingTasks

def add_trainingtask(request, task_id):
    #make sure we have a valid Task object, or redirect.
    #you could also use a try/except Task.DoesNotExist and show an error
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)

    form = TrainingAddForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():                
            tt = TrainingTasks(
                trainee = request.user,
                task = task,
                date = form.cleaned_data['date'],
                ac_reg = form.cleaned_data['ac_reg'],
                wo_no = form.cleaned_data['wo_no'],
            )
            tt.save()
            #dont hard-code the url here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin_tot_tasks'))
    return render(request, 'admin/tot/trainingtasks/add.html', {'form': form,
        'task' : task})
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Sorry, probably my question was unclear. 
I use the Task object to show the information behind it to the user who adds the TrainingTaskobject. So I took the task_id and grab the according record from the database.
But I want to prevent the user from changing the choosen task, that's why I disabled the field.

Comment: Hi. If you don't want them to change the Task object, why include it in the form data at all? You're passing the task_id through the query string, so you can just pick it up through the parameters passed to your view.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Cause I wanted to actually _show_ the information contained in the related Task object.
But maybe you're right, I'll just show the information in the template.
Thx for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help out. I've updated the code example to show passing the task object to the template.